# Drivers for stereo camera

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've purchased a cool stereo camera, very low cost and I'm hoping it works well.  However there is a pretty big issue, I can't get it to play nice with ROS.  It is a single board with two lenses and one USB cable.

Camera: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00VG32EC2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VG32EC2)

I've tried a couple ideas such as the opencv based video streamer, and even a driver written for this camera but so far no luck.  Does anyone know of a good way to tackle this problem?  I've tried looking for a sub address or something along those lines.  When using the opencv streamer address 0 yields a side by side image from the right and left lens.  The idea here would be to have a node grab the images and publish them to something like right/Image_raw and left/Image_raw.

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281863/drivers-for-stereo-camera/) by [jake3991](https://answers.ros.org/users/33577/jake3991/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2018-07-10**:
I suspect that the camera you have and the one in the link are slightly different.  The one in the link ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00VG32EC2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VG32EC2)) is not synchronized and is visible as two USB devices, for which your driver (http://wiki.ros.org/elp_stereo_camera) is intended.

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2018-07-10**:
My guess is you have the synchronized version (https://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=ELP-960P2CAM-V90-VC), which is a single USB device and streams as one video (side-by-side).  If so, as others suggest, I'd split and republish as two images. Then, feed it to any stereo processing node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You say you found a driver for this camera, but you don't provide a link to it or describe how it doesn't work. That makes it hard to help you.

The OpenCV streaming interface sounds promising. Being able to grab the left and right images simultaneously is a huge advantage when dealing with stereo cameras. I suspect the boundary between the images doesn't move, so if the existing driver doesn't work out you should be able to write one that uses OpenCV's streaming interface. I'd just grab the dual image, split it apart and publish the left and right images separately (with identical timestamps).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0